# How do I calculate a hypothetical trade?

Tags: exchange-rate, charts, trade

Say I had 1 Bitcoin at the start of the trade yesterday

```
 @ 01-27 14:29
```

and the price was

```
 USD : 263.95872470902
```

So, I sold the whole Bitcoin at the average price

Then

```
 @ 01-29 10:57
```

I bought back as much Bitcoin as the new price would let me again at the average price of

```
 USD : 233.55771464647
```

The price data was taken from crypto-prices.com I just don't see how that could be worked out. I know how to use preev.com to calculate the 'current' value but I don't understand how I would calculate a previous value and work out the difference / or would be, pretend profit.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is essentially about elementary math and as such not a good fit for a Bitcoin experts' question and answer site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`263.95 [USD/BTC] / 233.56 [USD/BTC] * 1 [BTC] = 1.13 [BTC]`, i.e. for each BTC you sold at the higher price, you can rebuy 1.13 BTC at the lower price.

The underlying concept is explained on [Wikipedia: Cross-multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-multiplication).